# MVC razor @Item.ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code that has @item.ID from razor:

```
    <a href="#" id="deleteitem(@item.ID)">Delete</a>
```

When I do view source, it shows up as deleteitem(766). Note that I do not want it to show up with the ( ). I like it to show as deleteitem766

If I do the following

```
    <a href="#" id="deleteitem@item.ID">Delete</a>
```

it does not recognize @item.ID value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="#" id="deleteitem@(item.ID)">Delete</a>
```